# Change zoom and rotate without re-rendering PDF.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I am adding a pdf viewer built with the pdf.js Display API (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js). Currently, each pdf is only a single page. I want to allow the user to change the zoom and rotation of the pdf but it seems that the only way to do so it by modifying the `viewport` when calling the `render` function.

ex.

`viewport = PDFPageProxy.getViewport({ scale: newScale, rotation: totalRotation });`

`PDFPageProxy.render({ canvasContext, viewport})`

This means that every time the user zooms or rotates the page, the whole pdf must be re-rendered and with an individual page size of ~1.5MB, the time for the RenderTask to resolve can be nearly a second.

I see that in the "Viewer" offered by pdfjs, there are setter methods `currentScale` and `pagesRotation`. https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/d08895d6591b8b3233676a2ffa6a2c294cb70df7/web/pdf_viewer.js#L163-L225
Confoundingly, when testing the same 1.5MB pdf page in the Viewer, the zoom and rotate actions are nearly instant.

Is there a better way to change the zoom and rotation of a pdf using the pdf.js Display API? How does the Viewer achieve such performant changes?

Answer (score 0):

since it's only one page why not catching the page as an image in the browser using the canvas internal api then manipulate it by rotating or anything as you want without rerendering the whole pdf each time you want to perform a UI operation?

Comment: That's a good suggestion but there are reasons why we have gone with PDFs and I am trying to improve the performance when displaying them.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF.js lazyloads PDF pages，it only renders pages visible near the viewport.

I think you should stick to the re-render approach, because if you don't re-render, you must use existing DOM and do some transform to make the view look exactly what you want, but this will affect all pages because you didn't implement lazyload, and the transform may break some internal API.